# Running Metafont in TeXLive in Windows

Tags: metafont

I have a user defined font, created with a small collection of .mf files. I am using this font for many documents and work on them using TeXLive in Windows.  I did not create the user defined font, but I have decided to modify it. The problem is that when I make a change to the Metafont file, it does not show up in my documents.  I can run Metafont, but I don't know the right parameter to say where the file should go.  I also think that if I could delete some existing file, then just running TeX would cause Metafont to do the right thing. But I don't know what file to delete to make that happen.
The folder structure is  c:\TeXLive\2021.  The Metafont files are located in c:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\source\local\neveln.
Any help would be very appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: The tfm and pk files are normally  in texmf-var, in the fonts folder. If you delete them, that will trigger a recreation.

Comment: Both the pk and tfm folders under texmf-var/fonts folder are empty.

Comment: Perhaps you have a user texmf-var. Check your log-file. At the end it should show the pathes to the pk-fonts.

Comment: That was it.  Thtank you.  I found the files under Users.  I deleted them and it triggered the rerunning of Metafont.